# Is there a way to tell what technology was used to build an iPad app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mobile

I have to develop an iPhone/iPad app and I've done a ton of research on the subject, and made my decision about what to use.  I've also been asked to review a number of mobile apps in our industry and I've been doing this.

Now I'd like to be able to see what technology was used in these various other products, so I can compare how I feel about an app with how it was made (native, PhoneGap, MonoTouch, etc.).  I understand that anyone can make a bad app with a good platform, and vice versa, but it would at least give me some feel for the technology.

So the question is: is there a way to tell what technology was used to build an iPhone/iPad app?

**Note:** Let me stress that I don't want to reverse-engineer the app or steal their secrets or anything, I just want to know what tools they used to build it.

Comment: You could email the devs and ask, or check out their blogs / twitter feeds. Except for decrypting the binaries and class dumping them that's probably your best bet.

Comment: @CarlVeazey: Thanks, I guess I'll just stick with the simple approach then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the apps you KNOW were made in a particular framework you can often cross reference to figure out other apps frameworks.

It merely takes experience and attention to detail.